# PlotLegends doesn't work on Plot3D-V8.0.0

Tags: plotting, legending, version-8

I am trying to plot in 3D and I need to use `PlotLegend`. My code is

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
Evaluate[PlotLegends]
Plot3D[Tanh[H/T], {T, 0, 300}, {H, 0.001, 1}, 
PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Framed[
    "Energy Dependance on Magnetic Field H and Absolute Temperature \
T"], 13, Red, Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]], 
 Background -> LightGray, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[.65 (1 - z)]], 
 AxesLabel -> {T[kelvin], H[tesla]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
 ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> Full, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

While I use `` Needs["PlotLegends`"] `` I don't seem to be able to plot a legend. I get an error saying

*Plot3D::optx: Unknown option PlotLegends in Plot3D[...]*

How can this be fixed?

Comment: This is an example from the documentation on how to use `PlotLegend`: `ShowLegend[
 Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], {ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1] &, 10, 
  " 1", "-1", LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I returned to the problem after reading the comments above. In version 8, the PlotLegends -> option works for Plot[] but not for Plot3D[]. For Plot3D, you will have to use ShowLegend[], as demonstrated below:

```
ShowLegend[
 Plot3D[Tanh[H/T], {T, 0, 300}, {H, 0.001, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Framed[
     "Energy Dependance on Magnetic Field H and Absolute Temperature \
T"], 13, Red, Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]],(*Background->
  LightGray,*)ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[.65 (1 - z)]], 
  AxesLabel -> {T[kelvin], H[tesla]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
  ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
  Mesh -> Full], {{{Graphics[{White, Circle[{0, 0}, 0]}], Tanh[H/T]}},
   LegendPosition -> {1.1, -.4}}]
```

This becomes simpler in version 9, where you can use PlotLegends-> if you like

```
Plot3D[Tanh[H/T], {T, 0, 300}, {H, 0.001, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Framed[
    "Energy Dependance on Magnetic Field H and Absolute Temperature \
T"], 13, Red, 
   Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]],(*Background->LightGray,*)
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[.65 (1 - z)]], 
 AxesLabel -> {T[kelvin], H[tesla]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
 ClippingStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> Full, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend["Expressions"]]
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it is still not working. I keep getting the error message that `Plot3D::optx: Unknown option PlotLegends in Plot3D[...]`

Comment: Try the revised code above.

Comment: It's working!!! Thank you very much!!! However I noticed something weird... I cannot rotate the plot...Is this suppossed to happen?

Comment: Do you mean click-and-drag rotation, or manually specifying the angle in the Plot3D command?  p.s. do a brother a favor and accept my answer above?